# Bluebird - promisification - promisifyAll of 'email-templates' Node Module - Send mail

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, node-modules, email-templates

I am trying to convert `email-templates` node module into promise. I am using **bluebird** for promisification but it couldn't converted.

```
var emailTemplates = Promise.promisifyAll(require('email-templates'));
```

Is promisification  node module supports this conversion or Am I doing any mistake?

**EDITED :**

I am doing like this now but wanna convert this to bluebird promise.

```
var emailTemplates = require('email-templates');
var path = require('path');
var templatesDir = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..', 'assets/templates');
var postmark = require('postmark');

var postmarkKey = MY_POSTMARK_KEY;
var postmarkClient = postmark(postmarkKey);

module.exports = {
  sendEmail : function (templateName, locals, callback) {    
            emailTemplates(templatesDir, function (err, template) {
                if (err)
                    return callback(err, null);
                else {
                    template(templateName, locals, function (err, html, text) {
                        if (err) {                        
                            return callback(err, null);
                        }    
                        else {
                            postmarkClient.send({
                                From: locals.from,
                                To: locals.to,
                                Subject: locals.subject,
                                HtmlBody: html
                                TextBody: text
                            }, function (err, responseStatus) {
                                if (err) {                                
                                    return callback(err, null);
                                }
                                else {
                                    return callback(err, responseStatus);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: And why do you say it isn't working?  What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

`emailTemplates` is a function, so you'd do:

```
var emailTemplates = Promise.promisify(require('email-templates'));
```

The problem is that it does not behave well since the function itself has a callback argument, so you'd have to do:

```
emailTemplates().then(function(template){
    Promise.fromNode(template.bind(null, "template-name")).then(...
});
```

Comment: I did with node style callback but as I mentioned in my Que I wanna convert this to bluebird promise. Can you help me more in this. I understand the way you explain but I couldn't combine that all.

Answer (score 0):

Promisify missbehaved for me as well, so i made a manual promisification.

```
var postmark    = require("postmark");
var client      = new postmark.Client("POSTMARK_API_TEST");
var Promise     = require('bluebird');

exports.sendInviteEmail = function(email) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.sendEmail({
            "From": "donotreply@example.com", 
            "To": "target@example.us", 
            "Subject": "Test", 
            "TextBody": "Test Message"
        }, function(error, result) {
            if(error) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    });
    return promise;
}
```